# Blank screen on new react native project

Tags: react-native, expo

I created a react native app with expo. However, when I run it using `expo start` I get a fully white screen with nothing else displayed.

Screenshot:

[image: error showed in cmd]

Code :

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: post the code and/or the error , you have given very limited information regarding the issue

Comment: It's a new project nothing is changed I create this with intial commands all code is as it as but when I run this nothing is on screen

Comment: at least add the error screen shot

Comment: @ShoyebMemon hello i add error and code please take a look at it and help to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually a network error. Try using `npx expo start --offline`

Comment: How to overcome the network error? Node is the ultimate source of frustration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running it on device, it might be because of styling of `Text`. Try giving some style to it:

```
<Text style={{color: "black"}}>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
```